# I dont understand why in banked roadway, $\text{(magnitude of normal force)}\cdot\cos x = F_g$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Normal force's magnitude is $F_g\cdot\cos \theta$ on an inclined plane therefore shouldn't the $y$ component of the normal force be

$$F_g\cdot\cos \theta \cdot\cos \theta ~~\text{and not }~~~F_g$$

(since there is no reason to believe the normal force's $y$ component is $F_g$ )

Comment: If the normal force's $y$ component was not $F_g$ then the car would accelerate up or down. Does the car accelerate up or down?

Comment: It doesn't. And I now understand why normal force's y component is Fg. So normal force's magnitude is not Fg×cosx in banked roadway? It is just valid in inclined plane?

Comment: If the car is not accelerating up or down then the normal force's magnitude would have to be $\frac{F_g}{cos x}$ (Also normally an angle would be called $\theta$, not $x$ but I kept it the same as in your equation)

Comment: Thanks! (I just didn't know how to add ceta symbol so I just used x instead)